# How to set cell width in cventry using awesome-cv?

Tags: moderncv

I would like to understand how I can set the cell width for the description item in cventry which is used in both awesome-cv and moderncv. Please see screenshot below to illustrate what I would like to achieve as well as a MWE. Does anyone has an advice?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\entrycv}[5]{
    \begin{tabular}{1\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        \ifempty{#3#4}
            {{#1} & {#2} \\
            {#5}}
            {{#1} & {#2} \\
            {#3} & {#4} \\
            {#5}}
    \end{tabular}
}


\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \begin{tabularx*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth -4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {{#1} & {#4} \\}
      {{#2} & {#3} \\
      {#1} & {#4} \\
      {#5}{}
      }
   \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth -5cm}}{{#5}}
  \end{tabularx*}%
}


\begin{document}

\entrycv{Date}{Job Description}{apple}{New York City, United States}{}
{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\vspace{2cm}

\cventry{Date}{Job Description}{apple}{New York City, United States}{}
{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\ %manual break which actually should be performed by cell width
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it currently is, your `entrycv` can not wirk. `tabular` does not accept a width argument. In order to get the `\cventry` command to work, use `\renewcommand` instead  of `\newcommand`.  Also replace `tabularx*` with `tabularx` and remove `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

Comment: More changes might still be needed.

Comment: Thanks, @leandriis. I adjusted the the `\entrycv` as follows:


`\newcommand{\entrycv}[5]{
    %\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|X|X|}
        \ifempty{#3#4}
            {{#1} & {#2} \\
            {#5}}
            {{#1} & {#2} \\
            {#3} & {#4} \\
            {#5}}
    \end{tabularx}
}`

This solves the issue with the adjustable width of the table, however, it is not working on the 5th argument which seems not to be included in the range (here: 5cm). Do you have another hint hereon?